# Creating docker image from another project

Tags: java, .net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have dockerized project, written in Java. I want to add containter for next module. The problem is that I did not write this module, and I was written in .NET. What should I write in dockerfile in my java project to have this container added?

First I need to write dockerfile, then I need to edit my .yml file.
This is the code that I wrote alone. During build, the error occures at 3rd line.

```
Error response from daemon: COPY failed: no source files were specified
Failed to deploy '<unknown> Dockerfile: ml/Dockerfile': Can't retrieve image ID from build stream
```

And this is the code of dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 as build-env
WORKDIR /home/user/Desktop/module
#copy the CSPROJ file and restore any dependecies
COPY /home/user/Desktop/module/*.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore
#copy project files and build release
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
#Generate runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0.9-alpine3.13-amd64
WORKDIR /home/user/Desktop/module
EXPOSE 8000
COPY --from=build-env /home/user/Desktop/module/out .
```

What should I change there, to have my code running properly?

And then I need to add description to docker-compose.yml but i really don't have a clue what should I write in it.
Also I do not know, if i should add .net module files to my java projects file structure.

Comment: Can you give me further information? Where is the Dockerfile located? Within your `/home/user/Desktop/module/` directory?

Comment: No, it is located in /home/user/IdeaProjects/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on your comment, it seems a problem with the file locations. You can't simply copy files from anywhere on your filessystem into the docker image. When you build the docker image, the build engine creates a context, from where you can copy files into the image, starting from the location of your Dockerfile.
In your case the Dockerfile resides in a different directory `/home/user/Desktop/module/` and therefore the 3th line fails, because you try to `COPY /home/user/Desktop/module/*.csproj .`

Try to move the Dockerfile into `/home/user/Desktop/module/`, replace the path with relative paths and rerun the build.

Comment: But then, how can I put this togheter to deploy it to server.

Comment: Once you have a working docker image build of your module, you can include this image in your docker-compose.yml
How you put the thing togheter for the server deployment depends. Do you want to use the docker-compose on your server?

Comment: yes. i want to use docker-compose on the server